# Consistent proxy for MSE in Least Squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-variables, condition-number

Suppose I have two $N \times M$, $N \gg M$ matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. Both have a structure and are generated using an analytical description from a set of iid random variables $X_i$. Both are assumed to have full column rank. For **example**:

$$
a_{ij} = X_i^j \\
b_{ij} = \sum_{r=1}^R X_{(i-1)R+r}^j
$$

$a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ are the elements of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and $X_i$ random variables, e.g. Gaussian iid. Both are used in a LS setting, for example:

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{e} \\
\mathbf{\hat c} = (\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})^{-1} \mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{y}
$$

I would like to find a proxy for the MSE $\|\mathbf{\hat c}-\mathbf{c}\|_2$ whose expected value I can evaluate analytically. With proxy I mean that the quantity is consistently smaller (or greater) if the MSE is smaller (or the other way round). My objective is to proof that a matrix generated with the second method is always "better" than a matrix generated with the other method.

I was thinking about the following proxies:

1. Condition number
2. "A optimality": $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})^{-1}$ (this is proportional to MSE!)
3. "D optimality": $\operatorname{det}(\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})$ or $\operatorname{det}(\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})^{-1}$
4. "E optimality": $\operatorname{min}\operatorname{max}\operatorname{eig}(\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})^{-1}$ or $\operatorname{max}\operatorname{min}\operatorname{eig}(\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})$
5. "T optimality": $\operatorname{Trace}(\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})$
6. Frame Potential: $\operatorname{Trace}((\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})^H \mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A})$

1) and 4) requires eigen-/singularvalue calculation which can't be done analytically. 2) requires matrix inversion which can't be done analytically. 3) requires determinant which can't be done analytically. I can easily calculate 5. analytically but it does not always seem to be consistent with the MSE. I can also analytically calculate 6. but this is only consistent if $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ have unit-norm rows which is not the case for my setup.

Basically I have an analytical expression for each entry (i.e., $a_{nm}$ and $b_{nm}$). However, I cannot do eigenvalues, matrix inversion etc.

Comment: It seems you are implicitly assuming that $A$ has a trivial null space.

Comment: It is a least squares problem hence I am assuming a skinny matrix $N \gg M$ and full column rank.