# Vandermonde matrix expected to be singular .... but not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-variables

Given a Vandermonde matrix $\mathbf{V}$ with Gaussian iid nodes. To simplify argument, assume $2\times 2$ with nodes $X_1, X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and iid, i.e., $\mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2)$.

$$
\mathbb{E}\det(\mathbf{V}) = \mathbb{E}\left\{\left| \begin{matrix} X_1 & X_1^2 \\ X_2 & X_2^2 \end{matrix} \right| \right\} = \mathbb{E}\left\{ X_1 X_2^2 - X_2 X_1^2 \right\} = \mathbb{E}\left\{ X_1 X_2^2 \right\} - \mathbb{E}\left\{X_2 X_1^2 \right\} = \\
= \mathbb{E}\left\{ X_1 \right\} \mathbb{E}\left\{ X_2^2 \right\} - \mathbb{E}\left\{X_2 \right\} \mathbb{E}\left\{X_1^2 \right\} = 0
$$

So a Vandermonde matrix is expected to be singular (I can generalize this with Laplace expansion). It implies that at least one eigenvalue is zero.

Next, calculate:

$$
\mathbb{E}\det(\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{V}) =
\mathbb{E}(\det\mathbf{V})^2 =
\mathbb{E}\left\{ (X_1 X_2^2 - X_2 X_1^2)^2 \right\} =
\mathbb{E}\left\{ X_1^2 X_2^4 \right\}
-2\mathbb{E}\left\{ X_1 X_2^2 X_2 X_1^2 \right\}
+\mathbb{E}\left\{X_2^2 X_1^4 \right\} =
\mathbb{E}\left\{X^2\right\}\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^4 \right\}
-2\mathbb{E}\left\{ X_2^3 X_1^3 \right\}
+\mathbb{E}\left\{X^2\right\} \mathbb{E}\left\{ X^4 \right\} = \\
2\mathbb{E}\left\{X^2\right\}\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^4 \right\}
-2\mathbb{E}\left\{ X_2^3 X_1^3 \right\} = \\
2\mathbb{E}\left\{X^2\right\}\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^4 \right\}
-2\mathbb{E}\left\{ X^3 \right\}^2 = 6\sigma^6
$$

This follows from $\det(\mathbf{A B}) = \det(\mathbf{A})\det(\mathbf{B})$ and $\det(\mathbf{A}^T) = \det(\mathbf{A})$. The result is nonzero, implying no zero eigenvalues.

However, $\mathbf{A}^T$ has the same eigenvalues as $\mathbf{A}$. Hence:

$$
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i \\
\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{v}_i \\
= \lambda_i (\lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i) = \lambda_i^2 \mathbf{v}_i
$$

Therefore the eigenvalues should be related by a square and if $\mathbf{A}$ contains a zero eigenvalue, so should $\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A}$.

Where does the contradiction come from?

Comment: The fact that the expectation of the determinant be zero does not mean that the matrix is expected to be singular. A $2\times 2$ Vandermonde matrix is singular iff the two numbers $X_1$ and $X_2$ are equal, and you surely see that you donot expect two normal iid variables to be equal!

Comment: In fact, the determinant is nonzero with probability 1.

Comment: There is finite probability that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identical. I am aware of the determinant formula for a Vandermonde matrix which also states that. However, what is then wrong about my calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The expected value of the determinant is $0$" is not the same thing as "the determinant is expected to be $0$".  In a simpler example, if $X = +1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$, then $\mathbb E[X] = 0$, but $X$ is never $0$.

Comment: I do not understand why the two phrases should not be identical. And I do not understand why the simpler example has anything to do with $\mathbb{E}\det$. Could you elaborate a bit more? Maybe you can directly relate what about my calculation is wrong/misleading.

Comment: @divB Don't get caught up in the language. Words do not mean the same thing necessarily when they are used in math. In particular, the value of the expectation has little to do with with what you would expect the value to be. The term "expectation" is not something you can turn into a verb and apply conjugation rules to. You could just as well represent the concept with a picture of Santa Claus.

Comment: @MattSamuel: That's my question. Maybe someone can translate both cases formally to math. For me they are the same. Ultimately I have two structured matrices (one of them is Vandermonde) but the data is random - as in the example above. Now I want to show that one is "better" than the other. For example, its determinant (expected determinant) is larger than for the other structure and hence structure A is better than structure B.

Comment: @divB You are equating the expected value of the determinant being zero with there being a high probability of the determinant being zero. In fact there is a zero probability of the determinant being zero or any other specific value, but the values are roughly centered around zero.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Ok, I see. Then $\mathbb{E}\det$ is maybe not the best way to assess the quality of a structured matrix. For example, $\mathbb{E}\det\mathbf{V}=0$ for any size Vandermonde matrix. But in reality, the larger the Vandermonde matrix, the worse its condition number. Can you think of a better way to prove that one structure is better than another?

Comment: @divB I don't know what a structured matrix is. It sounds like you may perhaps want to post a new question.

Comment: A structured matrix ist just a matrix that has a structure but the data itself are RVs. Just as the Vandermonde matrix above. I asked that already but got no responses so far: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930769/consistent-proxy-for-mse-in-least-squares

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\Bbb E(\det(V^TV)) = \Bbb E(\det(V)^2) = \Bbb E(\det(V)^2) = [\Bbb E(\det(V))]^2
$$
$\det(V)$ is a random variable with mean $0$ and non-zero variance.  It is not particularly likely that $\det(V)$ will be exactly $0$.

Comment: This is true but that the second terms is true follows from the first part in my example. So it does not change anything.